# Syntax for <Style>?

Tags: html

I've tried Googling to find all the attributes for the "style=" parameter.  Surely it must be easy to find, right?  Just a simple list of all the possible attributes?

I couldn't find anything.  Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing.  Anybody have a favourite cheat sheet of attributes on a site somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to Salesforce and just basic HTML styling. The style attribute takes a string of CSS style declarations.

i.e. `<apex:outputText style="font-weight: bold;">Bold Stuff</apex:outputText>`

Exhaustive list of attributes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Getting started tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

W3 spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!  I put it here because I was working on a VF page, but I see that I should have just put it in the regular HTML section.  Sorry for that, but thank you for the help there!  I was definitely searching using the wrong keywords!